# Is my HTML "leaking", because it is showing abnormal behavior

Tags: html, css, debugging, templates

When I put this code outside of the `<table>`...it will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#stars-wrapper1").stars({
        oneVoteOnly: true
    });
});
</script>
<form>
    <div id="stars-wrapper1">
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="1" title="Very poor" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="2" title="Poor" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="3" title="Not that bad" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="4" title="Fair" />
        <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="5" title="Average" />
    </div>
</form>
```

However, when I put this inside the

```
<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

Then, it will show the 1 2 3 4 5. Does anyone know what  is wrong with the table?

```
<table width="100%" style="border: 0px none ;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 110px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top" align="right">
    <form>
        <div id="stars-wrapper1">
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="1" title="Very poor" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="2" title="Poor" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="3" title="Not that bad" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="4" title="Fair" />
            <input type="radio" name="newrate" value="5" title="Average" />
        </div>
    </form>

</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 20px;" valign="top"><div class="resultItem" style="float: left;">
           stutt here
          </div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Edit: I am using a JQUERY Star rating plguin. http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/index.html#demos

It allows me to have 5 stars for rating.

Comment: Can you edit your post?  I'm guessing you have some HTML tags in there that need to be escaped: "When I put this code outside of the ...it will work."

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using a specific jQuery plugin, if so, which one is it?

Comment: I am using JQuery 5-star-rating plugin: http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/index.html#demos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `align="right"` from your `<td>` tag.  It looks like the titles are converted to links, and always present, but normally not visible.

The `align="right"` seems to bring the link text in to view beneath a CSS sprite of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a CSS issue, esp if you're using star images. it probably can't find your inputs inside your table.

Make sure that your CSS references your `#stars-wrapper1`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a jquery script that re-structures your HTML, so after the page loads, they aren't actually input fields any more, but nested divs.  You need some CSS, something like:

```
.ui-stars-star {
    text-indent: -999em;
}
```

Did this plugin come with some CSS for you?  (And if you are indeed using it, make sure their selectors will still apply to your elements after you put them in the table)